# Ubuntu - cron not running script

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ok, so I'm trying to set cron to run a bash script at a certain time. My bash script is essentially this

```
#!/bin/bash
espeak -g 3 "this is my text"
```

So from there, I went to the crontabs, and added in

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/my/script.sh
```

to see if it would run, but it didn't do anything. I changed the script to

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "this is my script"
```

to see if that would do anything, but no avail. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing `*/1 * * * * /path/to/my/script.sh` for `*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /path/to/my/script.sh`?

Comment: is it executable? does it rely on a certain environment being set? would you receive error email sent by cron deamon? have you tried using a simple script that just touches one file e.g. in /tmp to see if things work?

Comment: Where do you expect to see the output `this is my script` anyway?  I guess using the audio output (`espeak`) will also be a problem due to permission trouble.

Answer (score 2):

- Try to run the script manually and see if it echos out: `bash /path/to/my/script.sh`
- Does the file have the correct permissions?
- Try Outputting errors to a log file: `*/1 * * * * /path/to/my/script.sh > /path/to/my/error.log 2>&1`

Comment: Permission denied! Aha!